# Getting a specific piece of text from a beautifulsoup result Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get this number '96.40' from the following result

```
<div style="text-decoration: underline">


                                                                    96.40% 
                                                                </div>
```

This is my code:

```
result = s.get('example.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")
myData = soup.find("div", {"style": "text-decoration: underline"})
print(myData)
```

Comment: You have not asked any question or described any issue.

Comment: You probably want `attrs=` in front of that dict?

Answer (score 0):

You need to print

```
myData.text.strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the "text" from a tag you can use `.text` or `.get_text()`:

```
myData.text.strip()
```

or

```
myData.get_text(strip=True)
```

In addition you can replace the `%`:

```
myData.get_text(strip=True).replace('%','')
```

or by slice

```
myData.get_text(strip=True)[:-1]
```

#### Example

```
html = '''
<div style="text-decoration: underline">


                                                                    96.40% 
                                                                </div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
myData = soup.find("div", {"style": "text-decoration: underline"})
print(myData.get_text(strip=True).replace('%',''))
```

#### Output

96.40